# How to separate the variable in this IVP?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It gives me:

xy' = y + x^2*sinx

xdy = y + x^2*sinx

What do I do next then?

It is because dy - y = (x^2*sinx)/x don't seem to make any sense.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $$xy' = y + x^2 \cdot\sin x$$is not separable.

It is a linear equation which could be solved by integrating factor method.

Note that you have $$ y'-(1/x)y=x \sin x$$

The integrating factor is $1/x$ so you multiply your equation by $1/x$ and go from there.

Comment: I got y(x) = x(lnx - ln(pi)) because I was also given y(pi) = 0

Comment: It does not seem to be right. Check your word again.

Comment: What happened to $\sin x$?

Comment: Oh...wait...so I know e^int(-1/x^2 dx) equals 1/x. Then, I multiplied the whole equation again by 1/x?

Comment: yes you multiply the $ y'-(1/x)y=x \sin x$ by $1/x$ and go from there.

Comment: The integral of sinx/x^2 dx, I got cos(x) - sin(x)/x + C ? My final answer should be y(x) = x(cos(x) - sin(x)/x + 1)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Let $y = x z$ then
$$xy' = y + x^2 \sin x$$ becomes
$$x^2 z'= x^2 \sin x$$ which becomes simple. Solve it for $z$ and go back to $y$.